# In Clojure, difference between function, quoted function and sharp-quote function

Tags: function, clojure, quote

In clojure, I'd like to know what are the differences between the three below.

```
(println (map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))) 

(println (map '+ '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))) 

(println (map #'+ '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)))
```

The results are

```
(5 7 9) 

(4 5 6) 

(5 7 9)
```

I can't understand the second one's behavior.

I feel the first one and the third one are the same in clojure which is Lisp-1 
and doesn't distinguish between evaluating a variable and the identically named function.

This may be a basic question, but there seems not to be enough infomation. Please teach me.

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, in clojure it is idiomatic to describe literal sequences with vectors instead of quoted lists.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Regarding the third case, in contrast to Common Lisp, `#'+` does not read as `(function +)` and refer to the value of the symbol `+` in the function namespace, since Clojure does not have a function namespace.  Instead, it reads as `(var +)` and refers to the `var` called `+`.  Applying a `var` is the same as applying the value stored in the `var`.

In the second case, you are repeatedly applying a symbol to a pair of numbers.  This is valid by accident.  Applying a symbol to a map is the same as indexing into that map:

```
user> ('a {'a 1, 'b 2, 'c 3, '+ 4})
1
user> ('+ {'a 1, 'b 2, 'c 3, '+ 4})
4
```

If you supply a second argument, it is used as the default value in case no matching key is found in the map:

```
user> ('+ {'a 1, 'b 2, 'c 3} 4)
4
```

Since in each iteration, you apply the symbol `+` to a pair of numbers, and since a number isn't a map and therefore doesn't contain `+` as a key, the second argument is returned as the default value of a failed match.

```
user> ('+ 'foo 4)
4
user> ('+ {} 4)
4
user> ('+ 1 4)
4
```

Comment: Great answer. Clear explanation of not immediately obvious behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matthias.  I could understand what #' means. I didn't realize Var, and I ignored it, but this time I could understand it more deeply.   I also could understand the 2nd code behavior. Thank you.